# Need help figuring out the $Allshares parameter

Tags: powershell-3.0

2.1. The script will be named `Get-Shares.ps1`.
2.2. The function will be named `Get-Shares`.
2.3. The function takes two parameters:

- `$ComputerName` = the computer to check for shares.
- `$AllShares` = if blank will only get non-$ shares, else show all shares.

Need help with the `$AllShares` parameter.

I don't need you to figure out the commands to get the shares. Here they are:

Show non-$ shares:

```
gwmi -Computer $ComputerName -Class Win32_Share |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*$" }
```

Show all shares:

```
gwmi -Computer $ComputerName -Class Win32_Share
```

Comment: Did you review the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/3.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters) about function parameters? For further help with your homework please show the full code you currently have for your function.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to make    $AllShares = if blank will only get non-$ shares, else show all shares.... I don't understand how to do the if, else part of it.

Comment: `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced` `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` Will be very much helpful Regards, kvprasoon

Comment: function global:Get-Shares(){
 
 .EXAMPLE
 }
 #>
 param (
  [string]$Computername, [string]$Allshares
 )
 
 $computername = 'localhost'
  
 if ($ComputerName -notlike 'localhost') {
 gwmi -Computer $ComputerName -Class Win32_Share | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*$" } 
 
 } 
 else {
 gwmi -Computer $computername -Class Win32_Share 
}
}

Comment: Am  I on the right path? I still can only get it to do one or the other.

Comment: You might be at the beginning of the right path. However, as it is you're not evaluating `$AllShares` anywhere in your code sample. Also, the way you want to use it calls for a switch rather than a string parameter. And please [edit] your question if you need to provide additional information. Code in comments is unreadable.